# Dynamic Values in Email Template

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a pick-list on my form, the selected value of which i want to use in an email template. However the value is not getting populated in the email template.

what should i do to achieve this Out of box without writing any java-script ?

Comment: which is it ? 4, 2011 or 2013 ? Pick the actual one.

Comment: Select Proper Email Template Type and add required Field ..It will

Comment: Work ..i have done it many times..or explain your problem with scenario.