# Dynamic content in email templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, email-templates, dynamic-content

I have rails background and i'm working to implement something like as shown in the image[image]

My email template will have such tags. While sending the email to the client, his information will get filled up in the template. I found this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540118/dynamic-values-in-email-template) but there's no answer. I looked up and found [this](https://github.com/code-and-effect/effective_email_templates)gem, however i cant use it as it uses liquid templates and i was unable to implement it because of time limitation.

I know i can do the whole thing of finding `{{first_name}}` and replacing the content whenever a tag appears but i doubt if its an efficient way to implement it.

Please share your ideas and guidance. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @BLiu, I did not use any plugin for same. It was more like a text area where `{{` and `}}` would enclose the dynamic tags. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

I was a noob in rails when i posted this question and soon forgot it and an upvote reminded me about it. I got successful in making it work and sharing my solution if anyone's looking for it:

```
class DynamicTemplateModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.parse_template(template, attrs={})
    result = template
    attrs.each { |field, value| result.gsub!("{{#{field}}}", value) }
    # remove anything that resembles a field but did not match a known field name
    result.gsub!(/\{\{\.w+\}\}/, '')
    return result
  end

end
```

**Usage**: `DynamicTemplate.parse_template(body, details)`

where

```
details = {first_name: user.first_name, last_name: user.last_name, company: user&.company&.name, email_address: user.email}
```

and

```
body = "Hi {{first_name}} {{last_name}}, Your company {{company}} is registered with us successfully"
```

With the `parse_template` method, the new body will be as expected.

My main concern with [diofeher solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43610282/5805239) about replacing the string was security. So managed with this.

Hope this helps someone. Leave any suggestions to make it better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said before, you can use Liquid to replace it or you can try to use (http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/).

Another option is to replace the tags like that:

```
ERB.new(your_template.gsub("{{", "<%=").gsub("}}", "%>")).result
```

You would change the default print of variable to use `{{ }}` syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't do this. This is a very very un-secure way and prone to SQL Injection. Image that i have to replace `first_name` with value and the value of `first name` of some `user` is `User.delete_all`. If that gets replaced here, my string will be like `<%= User.delete_all %>`. I don't think i need to say anything else here. My database will collapse with all the data gone.

Comment: Oh, so this is going to be used by users? I thought it was going to be used only by your team.

Comment: this is required for the end users to prepare an template in which the tags will be replaced by data of users to whom the email is supposed to be sent. I've shared my solution. Suggestions on it are welcomed. Thanks